# Llenar un arreglo de fechas cada 15 minutos hasta que termine el día moment js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, momentjs

¿Cómo puedo llenar un array en javascript que tome como referencia la hora del momento y que de ahí agregue 15 minutos hasta finalizar el día?

Por ejemplo:

Hora: 16:12

array:
16:30
16:45
17:00
17:15

Código

```
function addMinutes() {
    var clock = new Date()

    //aquí veo cuantas horas le quedan al día para crear intervalos
    for (i = 0; i < 24 - moment().hour(); i++) {
        console.log(moment(clock[i]).add(15, 'minutes').format("HH:mm"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así (Explicación en comentarios del código)

```js
const tiempo = "16:12";

const [horas, minutos] = tiempo.split(":");

//Calculamos cual es el "cuarto de hora" actual basado en los minutos
//Es decir 00, 15, 30 o 45
let cuartoActual = Math.floor(minutos/15)*15;

//Iniciamos la fecha en la hora 0 de hoy y le asignamos la hora y los minutos del cuarto de hora actual
const fecha = moment().startOf("day").hour(horas).minute(cuartoActual);
const currentDay = fecha.date(); //Sacamos el dia actual de esa hora

const fechas = []; //Array para almacenar las fechas

fecha.add(15, "minutes");
while(fecha.date() === currentDay){   //mientras siga siendo el mismo dia
  fechas.push(fecha.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))  //agregamos la fecha
  fecha.add(15, "minutes") //Aumentamos 15 minutos
}

console.log(fechas);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excelente código y solución, funciona al 100%

Answer (score 0):

welcome recursion:

```
const moment = require('moment');

function getHoursFromDateToDate(fromDate, toDate, hours) {
     const mDate = moment(fromDate).clone().minutes(getNextQuarter(fromDate));
     hours.push(mDate.format("HH:mm"));    
     if (moment(toDate).diff(moment(fromDate), "seconds") / 60 > 15) 
         getHoursFromDateToDate(mDate.toDate(), toDate, hours);
}

function getNextQuarter(fromDate) {
    return (Math.trunc(moment(fromDate).minutes()/15)+1)*15;
}
var hours = [];
var initDate = moment().toDate();
var endDate = moment(initDate).clone().add(1, 'days').startOf('day').toDate();
console.log('dates:.......');
console.log(initDate);
console.log(endDate);
console.log('hours:.......');
getHoursFromDateToDate(initDate, endDate, hours);
console.log(hours);
```

Comment: Funciona bien, sin embargo, me costó un poco de trabajo adaptarlo.

Comment: gracias por el punto positivo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con la sentencia [**`do...while`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) para que primero ejecutes y luego evalúes. En este caso, lo que se ejecutará será los 15 minutos que se agregarán al tiempo actual, luego de esto, evalúa si el tiempo agregado en 15 minutos supera las 23:59 p.m. ya que si fuese más de éste tiempo, el tiempo sumado en 15 minutos se pasará el final del día, osea las 00:00 horas.

```js
function addMinutes() {
  var date = moment();
  var time = [];

  do {
    time.push(date.format("HH:mm"));
    date.add(15, 'minutes');
  } while (date <= moment("23:59", "HH:mm"))

  return time;
}

console.log(addMinutes())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```